# Sesame 2.8.6 repository not persists

Tags: semantic-web, sesame

I have deployed Sesame 2.8.6 server and workbench on Wildfly-8.2.0.Final.

I created a new In Memory repository like this:

[image]

I clicked "Create" and the repository was created:

[image]

[image]

If I restart Wildfly-8.2.0.Final the repository that I created disappears. It doesn't persist. Am I missing something?

I also tried versions 2.8.5 and 2.8.4 and it was the same result: the repository did not persist.

When I tried version 2.8.3 of sesame the repository persisted.

Logs from [ADUNA_DATA]/OpenRDF Sesame/logs/main.log:

[image]

The repository folder (with the files: memorystore.data, lock\locked and lock\process) is created in the AppData\Roaming\Aduna\OpenRDF Sesame\repositories\ folder and it remains there after I restart the server. But when I try to access the repository by workbench/console after restart it fails. It doesn't find the repository although the data about it is stored on disk.

Update:

If I close the running Wildfly container then the repository does not persist and the "lock" folder from the [ADUNA_DATA]/OpenRDF Sesame/repositories/1234567/ is not deleted. 
But if I disable the wars first and after that I close the container the repository persists  and the "lock" folder from the [ADUNA_DATA]/OpenRDF Sesame/repositories/1234567/ is deleted. 
This is happening for Sesame versions 2.8.4 and higher.
In version 2.8.3 it works ok.
I don't know if this helps but I thought it might be some useful information.

Comment: Do the logs show anything? Does the user under which your servlet container runs have write permissions in the server's data directory?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra When I click the "Create" button,  the console shows that an exception was thrown org.openrdf.workbench.exceptions.BadRequestException: no such repository: <repositoryid>, but the repository is created... and works fine, but does not persist. The user has write permissions. I tried it on two distinct machines and on each of them the container was running locally.

Comment: I actually meant the Sesame server logs. See the Sesame documentation for pointers on how to find these

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I added the logs to my question.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you think the previous versions are more stable?

Comment: @msc87 Version 2.8.3 works fine from this point of view. I don't know how stable it is. I have been working with version 2.8.3 a period of 5-6 months I think. Now I am using version 2.8.6... it's a bit annoying because I have to close the Wildfly container with Ctrl+c, or disable the war first from the administration console to save data. If I close the container by hitting the X button on cmd window without doing first what I just mentioned I loose all my modifications. More than that I don't know what to say... The workbench has some bugs, be a little bit careful if you are using it.

Comment: @whitefang1993: I just issued a bug report in sesame working group. but thanks for your explanation. Although I did not get how to close the war first and whose war, the workbench?

Comment: @msc87 The openrdf-sesame.war... you have to disable this war file in the administration console if you are used to manage your deployments from there. After that you can close Wildfly. If you are not managing your deployments from there you have to close Wildfly by typing Ctrl-c in the command line window where the container is running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a repository on sesame workbench, when restart tomcat, it gone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897362/create-a-repository-on-sesame-workbench-when-restart-tomcat-it-gone)