# create a repository on sesame workbench, when restart tomcat, it gone

Tags: java, tomcat, sesame

I have created a repository named local.

You can see there are several repositories on the sesame server.

Then I restarted tomcat, connected to sesame workbench. Now all the repositories I just created is GONE!!(picture below)

[image: screenshot]

I don't understand, how can I find the repositories I JUST created?

I Just put the war file into the tomcat "webapps" folder. and start tomcat.

**Environment** :

OS: Windows 10

tomcat: 8.0.30

java: 1.8.0_60

Comment: Which version of Sesame are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a version of Sesame that has this bug: [SES-2346](https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-2346). If your JVM is not shut down cleanly, the in-memory store (and therefore Sesame Server's SYSTEM repository) does not persist. This bug was introduced in Sesame 2.8.4/4.0.0, and was fixed in Sesame 2.8.9/4.0.2.

The solution is to upgrade your version of Sesame to the latest release (at time of writing that's Sesame 4.1.1 or Sesame 2.8.10), and/or to make sure that you shut down tomcat cleanly (rather than just killing it).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm using  Sesame 4.0.0, I changed it to 4.1.1, It works!!

Comment: No problem. By the way, if you found this answer helpful, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer instead of thanking me in a comment. See [what to do when someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I saw that you marked this question with this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/32606229/4801267 that I have posted about 7 moths ago as possible duplicates. I have just tried out the following versions of sesame: 2.8.4, 2.8.9, 2.8.11, and 4.1.1 and my problem persists in all of them. When I create a new  in memory repository it doesn't persist after server restart, although I checked the persist option in the workbench at creation time. I used jboss-as-7.1.1.Final for versions 2.8.x and wildfly-8.2.0.Final for version 4.1.1.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I have to shut down the servers cleanly for persistence. I did not have this problem in version 2.8.3.